# Derivative of the absolute value $\vert x\vert^3$ with $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition - check my proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

Consider $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, ~~ f(x) = \vert x \vert ^3$$ Show that the first derivative exists and it holds $$f'(x)=3x\vert x\vert ~~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

My approach:

**edited**

For a $y > 0$: I want to show that $3y^2$ is the limit of $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. This means for any given $\epsilon >0$ I find a $\delta >0$ such that we have $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}~:\vert x - y\vert < \delta \Rightarrow \biggl|\frac{x ^3 - y^3}{x-y}- 3y^2\biggr| < \epsilon$. After some manipulations and a polynomial long division I get the following: $\biggl|\frac{x ^3 - y^3}{x-y}- 3y^2\biggr| =~ ... ~= \vert x^2-2y^2+xy\vert$. **But now I am stuck. How do I use this to show that the conition is satisfied?**

I run into the same problem when I try the other case:

For $y<0$: I want to show that $-3y^2$ is the limit of $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$. This means for any given $\epsilon >0$ I find a $\delta >0$ such that we have $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{<0}~:\vert x - y\vert < \delta \Rightarrow \biggl|\frac{y ^3 - x^3}{x-y}+ 3y^2\biggr| < \epsilon$. After some manipulations and a polynomial long division I get the same as in the "$y>0$-case": $\biggl|\frac{y ^3 - x^3}{x-y}+ 3y^2\biggr|=\biggl|\frac{x ^3 - y^3}{x-y}- 3y^2\biggr| =~ ... ~= \vert x^2-2y^2+xy\vert$. **How do I use this to show that the conition is satisfied?**

However, the last case seems to be the easiest one...

If $y=0$ then I have to take a closer look at the limit. I will use the $\epsilon$ -$\delta$-definition of the limit. So if a value $b$ is the limit then for any given $\epsilon >0$ I find a $\delta >0$ such that we have $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}~:\vert x - 0\vert < \delta \Rightarrow \biggl|\frac{\vert x \vert ^3 - 0}{x-0}-b \biggr| < \epsilon$. I will now set $b=0$ and check if the condition is satisfied.

$ \biggl|\frac{\vert x \vert ^3 - 0}{x-0}-0 \biggr| =  x^2$. Setting $\delta= \sqrt{\epsilon}$ shows that the limit exists and hence $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Did I use the $\epsilon$ -$\delta$-definition of the limit rigorously?

Comment: They probably wanted you to handle *all* cases with the definition.

Comment: @vonbrand, I have edited the post. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, since you only used the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition at $0$ (correctly, by the way, although I would have taken $\delta=\sqrt\varepsilon$). In all other cases, what you did was to “apply the rules of differentiation”.

Comment: I totally missed that point. Thanks, I will edit my question.

Comment: I found some errors in the manipulations I did and edited them, do you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Note that\begin{align}x^2-2y^2+xy&=x^2-y^2+xy-y^2\\&=(x-y)(x+y)+(x-y)y\\&=(x-y)(x+2y).\end{align}And, if you fix $y$ and $\varepsilon>0$, it is easy to show that there is a $\delta>0$ such that$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta\implies\bigl\lvert(x-y)(x+2y)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: I would proceed as follows: $$\vert \delta (x+2y)\vert = \vert \delta (x+y-y+2y)\vert \leq \delta \vert x \vert + 2\delta \vert y \vert \leq \delta^2 + \delta \vert y \vert + 2 \vert y \vert \delta= 3 \vert y \vert \delta+ \delta^2.$$ Then I choose $\delta := min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, where $\delta_1< \frac{\epsilon}{6\vert y\vert}$ and $\delta_2< \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$. This allows me to estimate: $$x^2-2y^2+xy < 3 \vert y \vert \delta+ \delta^2 < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon.$$ So I have found an appropriate $\delta$.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Do you think there is a swifter way to show it with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition? I found it kind of awkward.

Comment: I would have done something similar to what you did.